# How to call JavaScript method when click on p:calendar next and prevous icon?

Tags: primefaces

I am developing a project with `Primefaces`.

I need to clear the selected date in `p:calendar` so that, I have an idea to add a clear button with p:calendar component internally to clear the selected date when click on that clear button.

**Sample JavaScript Code:**

```
   function addClearButton()
        {
            var r = $('<input/>').attr({
                type: "button",
                id: "field",
                class: "ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all",
                onclick: "clearDate()",
                value: 'clear'
            });
                $('#field').remove();
                $("#ui-datepicker-div").append(r); // ui-datepicker-div is a default id(See on firebug). 
             }

   function clearDate()
    {
        $('#calenderId_input').val(""); //calenderId_input is a default id(See on firebug).  
    }
```

**Primefaces Component :**

```
 <p:calendar  id="calenderId" showButtonPanel="true" onclick="addClearButton();"/>
```

Here, I have added sample code which i have tried.

By using the above code,we can add button but when clicks on next or previous button that added button will automatically removed.

So,I need to call a `JavaScript` method when click on `p:calendar` next and previous button(icon) to add button or suggest me any new idea.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Showing what you tried already will help others to help you...

Comment: @TocToc Please see my updated question.

Comment: What you do in your sample code is totally different then what you posted in the title of your question. No relation at all. Why not add jquery eventhandlers to the buttons and from thatbadd the clear button again/

Comment: @Kukeltje Above code is to add clear button in calendar component...my doubt is how to call the js method when click on calendar next and previous button..because my added button cleared automatically when clicked on that next and previous button..so I had an idea when click on that next and previous button I will to call that above addClearButton() method to add button again, so that I asked how to call js method by click on that previous and next button of calendar..